# Misaligned element in Safari when centring using percentages

Tags: css, safari

[Website](http://69.195.124.106/~manosoph/curiousbookco/)

The small green bar below the carousel's  element is centred using 'left: 50%;' However, in my client's Safari 8.0.8 browser the green bar is shifted noticeably right. In my Safari version of 9.1.1 the issue is not there, though.

CSS used:

```
.text-center h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 2px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #16656e;
}

h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #16656e;
}
```

Is there a known issue with centring using percentages in some Safari versions?

[image: Safari misalignment of :after element]

Comment: can you post your css?  green bar is that the one that looks very dark green like almost black??

Comment: It is the small 2px high 40px wide bar below 'Made to Measure' and above the yellow button. Added CSS to OP. Thanks

Comment: You can try instead of the translateX + left 50% to center to use instead, {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0, right:0;} see if that centers it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the width of the element extended right from the centre of the page, so I just needed to set margin-left: -20px; to adjust it.